# Gradle build error using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

After I created new project using cordova and added android platform, I got this error while building the project for first time

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/1.5.0/gradle-core-1.5.0.jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download artifact 'gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0)'
      > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\nienb\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download4337332192574000593bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\nienb\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\gradle-core\1.5.0\70915a3f0ef4243d4630ea23219f5445fac82700\gradle-core-1.5.0.jar'
```

any one could help ?

Comment: maybe just a network issue.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I'm not using any proxy. I also change the network connection, but the error still occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by downgrade gradle version from 1.5 to 1.3, both on main app and cordova plugin, but still looking for some official solutions

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue developing on Windows after upgrading to Cordova 6. Run cmd as administrator and it resolved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I noticed that when re-running the build, the file that the build got stuck on before would suddenly transfer just fine, but then the build failed on a different file.

I re-ran the build 4 or 5 times, and eventually it worked. I was running this in an administrator command prompt; not sure if that was important.